# Gradle Building Error while outputting the program

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I am facing an issue when I am Using Gradle to output my Android APP in Android Studio, I am getting such error, the error was there in sync, then I tried to sync and the AVD was working, and the sync worked, but now, maybe I face the same issue while using Gradle to output, and I think this might help, that I reset my laptop, so everything is removed, and I reinstalled Android Studio and everything, and this is my first test, and run for Gradle too.

**Here is my build.gradle which I get**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.10"
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle:1.5.10"
 
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
 
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
 
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Here is my error**

```
    Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kotlinKaptWorkerDependencies'.

> Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle:1.5.10.

Searched in the following locations:

- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle/1.5.10/kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle-1.5.10.pom

If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.

Required by:

project :app



Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

> **Who could help, that would be appreciated and would be happy, thank you...**

Comment: I am looking for some kind of solution, I have searched for a solution, some I didn't understand, some I did understand them, but didn't solve my error

Comment: Try adding mavenCentral() , `repositories {   mavenCentral() }`

Comment: I tried that before, but let me try again.

Comment: It is building, let us see the result, oh it worked, let me just confirm that.

Comment: Yeah, it worked, thank you.., kindly post that as an answer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add central Maven repository

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

**Possible cause of error** :
It seems currently android studio is trying to download library( `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle:1.5.10`) from location `"https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2"` , but for some reason it couldn't find [pom file](https://maven.apache.org/repository/central-metadata.html) as explained in the error.
**If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.**

Comment: But that passed, it came out with another issue